# Building Riak on CentOS from source

Tags: riak

I'm trying to build Riak 2.1.3 from source on CentOS 7. The build fails with `Uncaught error in rebar_core`.

The sequence of steps is the following:

1. Install Basho version of Erlang with kerl:

`$ ./kerl build git git://github.com/basho/otp.git OTP_R16B02_basho8 R16B02-basho8
$ ./kerl install R16B02-basho8  ~/erlang/R16B02-basho8
$ . ~/erlang/R16B02-basho8/activate`

2. Clone Riak git repo and build

`$ git clone https://github.com/basho/riak.git
$ cd riak
$ git checkout riak-2.1.3
$ make rel`

For this process I'm getting error:

`[juriy@dbvm riak]$ make rel
Using rebar.config.lock file to fetch dependencies
./rebar -C rebar.config.lock get-deps
Uncaught error in rebar_core: {'EXIT',
                               {undef,
                                [{crypto,start,[],[]},
                                 {rebar,run_aux,2,
                                  [{file,"src/rebar.erl"},{line,212}]},
                                 {rebar,main,1,
                                  [{file,"src/rebar.erl"},{line,58}]},
                                 {escript,run,2,
                                  [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,747}]},
                                 {escript,start,1,
                                  [{file,"escript.erl"},{line,277}]},
                                 {init,start_it,1,[]},
                                 {init,start_em,1,[]}]}}`

I also tried to build Erlang from the source, with the same result. Here's the exact list of commands:

`wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.basho.com/erlang/otp_src_R16B02-basho8.tar.gz
tar zxvf otp_src_R16B02-basho8.tar.gz
cd OTP_R16B02_basho8
./otp_build autoconf
./configure && make && sudo make install`

Answer (score 2):

[Please see my answer to your GitHub issue](https://github.com/basho/riak/issues/826#issuecomment-207806282).